# HTTP/2 with ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http2

I'm trying to get HTTP/2 working with ASP.Net Core 2.2. I'm testing on Windows 10 x64 1809.

I'm using the basic template with the following web host builder:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilderKestrel(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 35000,
                lo =>
                {
                    lo.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    lo.UseHttps(@"path to cert");
                });
        });
    return builder;
}
```

When using Chrome it accepts the certificate and shows the site over HTTPS. The problem is that it's using HTTP/1.1 and not h2 when checking the network requests in the devtools section.

Using `openssl s_client -connect 'host:35000' -cipher "EDH"` gives the following output:

```
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: FA0F0000C66FFFD36BE15AE79B2F48DF631EB83D0425DD534DAA278622CB30AE
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 2B10E9FD71B42328CAFAFBE18789777132565A98CE8CFD9B8E0452F6490929CB6D1B20AB57A000EDBFF40372C93EB547
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1552937526
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

The one thing that looks out of place is "No ALPN negotiated" and "Secure Renegotiation IS supported". Am I missing anything here?

[The msdn site lists the following requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#http2-support):

```
TLS version 1.2 or later
Renegotiation disabled
Compression disabled
Minimum ephemeral key exchange sizes:
Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE) [RFC4492] – 224 bits minimum
Finite field Diffie-Hellman (DHE) [TLS12] – 2048 bits minimum
Cipher suite not blacklisted
```

Not sure how I'd check most of these settings. Some of these seem like settings of the certificate, while others seem application specific.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you using to test your site?

Comment: @Barry Old would be underselling it (I really only use it to create self signed certs for testing), but I'll try it tomorrow with an up-to-date version and update it with the results.

Comment: OpenSSL before 1.0.2 didn’t support ALPN so won’t negotiate it - eve if your server supports it.

Comment: @Barry I'm running `OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018`, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Did you verify that you are targeting the right version? `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`

Comment: @kapsiR Sure, but fair point. It's self-hosted with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`, `<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>`, and using `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. I assume it might be a problem with the certificate, but no idea how to check that apart from the openssl output.

Comment: You can verify that if you e.g. generate a new one with `dotnet dev-certs https` and use the cert from the store with `lo.UseHttps(StoreName.My, "localhost", allowInvalid: true);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your case, but having similar issues, I've figured out an odd thing -

Here is the setup in the code that doesn't work -

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .UseKestrel(opt =>
                 {
                     int port = 44336;
                     opt.ListenAnyIP(port, listenOptions =>
                     {
                         listenOptions.UseHttps(@"cert.pfx", "...");
                         listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                     });
                 })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Now, **if I configure the same through the appsettings.json**, it suddenly starts serving requests over HTTP/2 -

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:44336",
        "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "./cert.pfx",
          "Password": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Other from that, here are my thoughts on the requirements:

- **TLS version 1.2 or later** - I guess any browser/Fiddler/Postman shall be able to provide you with this information.
- **Renegotiation disabled** - if I'm not mistaken, server renegotiation has been disabled since TLS 1.2. Otherwise, setting DisableRenegoOnServer registry key to a non-zero value shall help -   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\DisableRenegoOnServer|  DWORD=1
- **Compression disabled** - not sure, but probably it's about response compression you would set in your Startup code
- **Minimum ephemeral key exchange sizes** - you could check DevTools/Security tab in Chrome, and I know that FireFox could provide you with even more details. Check out [How-to-identify-the-Cipher-used-by-an-HTTPS-Connection](https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/207831828-How-to-identify-the-Cipher-used-by-an-HTTPS-Connection).
- **Cipher suite not blacklisted** - once you know about the connection, you could check [BadCipherSuites](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites)